# How Can I generate a file in RemoteServiceServlet and send it to a user?

Tags: gwt

Maybe I can disable RemoteServiceServlet response serialization or define RemoteService interface with method that returns ServletOutputStram? I would like not to save request in any database to file to process it in another request.

Comment: What do you actually want to do? I don't get it :(

Comment: I would like to be able to use RemoteServiceServlet as noraml servlet  and write binary data to the ServletOutputStream.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with the GWT RemoteServiceServlet. It wraps the whole http stuff and serializes it for you. Go with a separate servlet, that is the easiest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to provide a download to the user, you can do it like this:

1. Write another servlet which simply writes out the file content through the ServletResponse
2. Make sure you have a binary header and provide the filename in there, too.
3. In your client, make an `<iframe ..>` (The widget class for this is `Frame`) and point its url to your new servlet.

Due to the binary header your browser will now provide the user with a Save as.. popup. That should be all.