# How to Upload a file in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, gwt-rpc, gwt2

I have to Upload a file which can be of type , Doc, text.
The Size of the File is more the 1 MB.

I need the name , size , and the data of this file on sever side so that i can process it further.

How to do it?
What libaries i use for this.
Any sample code will be of great help.

Comment: I have asked similar question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086114/how-can-i-generate-a-file-in-remoteserviceservlet-and-send-it-to-a-user. There are probably no easy way, so I have chosen JSF to create this part of App.

Comment: @Damian  Can you please provide the sample code to understand what you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [Basic File upload in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111130/basic-file-upload-in-gwt)

Refer this also : [An Example](http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~FileUpload)