# How to Upload a file using GWT

Tags: java, gwt, file-upload, gwt-rpc, gwt2

I am new to GWT.

I am trying to Upload a file. I need the data and the name of the file on the server side.
the file is doc type and can be of size more then 1 MB to 5MB.

Plz suggest me How to do it. any sample code will be of great help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615567/how-to-upload-a-file-in-gwt same  question but havn't answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a really nice little libary called GwT-UPLOAD: http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/

There is a quick start guide here: http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/wiki/GwtUpload_GettingStarted

Comment: This GWT-UPLOAD Is uset to upload Images not the text file.
I want to only .doc or .txt n the size is Greater then 1 MB.

Comment: *"GWTUpload is a library for uploading files to web servers"* that means any file, not just images, this is a correct answer.