# How to Upload a file > 1 MB using GWT

Tags: java, gwt, file-upload, gwt-rpc, gwtupload

I am new to GWT.

I am trying to Upload a file. I need the data and the name of the file on the server side. the file is doc type and can be of size more then 1 MB to 5MB.

Plz suggest me How to do it. any sample code will be of great help.
Plz dont suggest gwtUpload. My File size is more then 1 MB.
gwtUpload doesn't support more the 512 Kb.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate question you asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616117/how-to-upload-a-file-using-gwt

Comment: @Deanna   coz nobody replied on the previous q. Its my observation that,if you question doesn't get response in 1 hr then forget it , nobody will give you expert comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `a form` instaed of `gwtUpload` class. See this related topic:

[Basic File upload in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111130/basic-file-upload-in-gwt)

Itt will help.

Comment: If i want to upload .doc or .pdf what thing i have to change

Comment: nothing, in Java language this is like a simple file, but if you want to edit, write or save properly this files (in the server side) you should import the relevant library i can suggest you:
.pdf -> iText Library
.doc, .docx, .excel -> Apache Poi Library
I think these are the best to manipulate these kind of documents....